# ng-repeat over 11k rows crashing

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a table (with a lot of data) with Angular, the table is already done with PHP but to add a filter is easier using Angular. PHP takes 10secs to draw the entire table of 11k rows, but Angular keeps going on and on, even Firefox tells me that a script is unasnwered. If I click continue, the message is shown again, if I click cancel the page does nothing, if I press debug it continues running but nothing is shown.

At first, I thought that drawing +11k rows in HTML with the ng-repeat was too much and that was causing the problem, so I added a limitTo (50) and also added a infinite scroll div. But it's still not showing anything and keeps on loading.

Here is some code:

```
<div ng-app='mainApp'>
    <div ng-init='values=[".$angularString."]' ng-controller='seeTickets as tickets'>
        <div infinite-scroll='tickets.loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
            Filtro: <input type='text' ng-model='globalSearch.$'/><br><br>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

                    app.controller('seeTickets', function(){
                        this.totalDisplayed = 50;

                        this.loadMore = function(){
                            this.totalDisplayed += 50;
                        }
                    });
            </script>
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="value in values | filter:globalSearch | limitTo:tickets.totalDisplayed">
                    <td> {{value.id_ticket}} </td>
                    <td> {{value.ticket_date}} </td>
                    <td> {{value.ticket_subject}} </td>
                    <td> {{value.ticket_from}} </td>
                    <td> {{value.ticket_to}} </td>
                    <td> {{value.ticket_priority}} </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to work this out? Why it's keep on loading even if I set limitTo?

Comment: If all you are using angular for is to create a table would probably be better off using something like jQuery Datatables and a json feed. Otherwise 11K rows in DOM is too many at once anywhere.. and angular watchers on this would be far too excessive for that many displayed at once without filtering/pagination

Comment: The porpose of using Angular for creating the table is the easy way of handling filters with Angular

Comment: So are you using angular for other parts of app also?

Comment: No, the whole Angular is there, but I'm most interested in the input text, that is the filter. But I'm not able to show the table, even with the limitTo

Comment: Suggest using a table module that has already been optimized for better performance and has features you need

Comment: @AleOtero93 Can you post your globalSearch function? I believe that could be causing some issues.

Comment: @Tyler Sorry, I dont have access to the code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add `track by $index` to **ng-repeat** like this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="value in values | filter:globalSearch | limitTo:tickets.totalDisplayed track by $index">
     ...
 </tr>
```

Comment: one way binding would help too